# DataPower SSL config for "Fetch" results in "unable to get SSL Profile''

Tags: github, ssl-certificate, api-gateway, ibm-datapower

We have a javascript file hosted on GitHub that I'd like to fetch:

[image]

**Error logs:**

```
172416  cli error   320673          0x81000224  === Line 2: copy -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mmxxxxx/abc/master/shim_mpgw_mapping.js store:///js/shim_mpgw_mapping.js
172416  audit   error   320673          0x82400020  (admin:default:web-gui:10.106.170.13): (config)# copy -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mm58169/datapower7/master/shim_mpgw_mapping.js store:///js/shim_mpgw_mapping.js
172416  audit   error   320673          0x8240002e  (admin:default:*:*): Copying file "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mm58169/datapower7/master/shim_mpgw_mapping.js" to "store:///js/shim_mpgw_mapping.js" failed
172416  cli error   320673          0x810002e7  File copy failed - destination URL could not be opened: store:///js/shim_mpgw_mapping.js
172416  file    error   320673          0x8100015c  Copying file "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mm58169/datapower7/master/shim_mpgw_mapping.js" to "store:///js/shim_mpgw_mapping.js" : failed
172416  system  warning 320673          0x8040000a  destination URL could not be opened: store:///js/shim_mpgw_mapping.js
172416  network error   31711           0x80e0005a  Cannot establish SSL credentials (credential is NULL), URL: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mm58169/datapower7/master/shim_mpgw_mapping.js'.
172416  network warning 31711           0x80e00058  SSL connection to 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mm58169/datapower7/master/shim_mpgw_mapping.js' failed, unable to get SSL Profile ''
172416  network warning 31711           0x80e00058  SSL connection to 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mm58169/datapower7/master/shim_mpgw_mapping.js' failed, unable to get SSL Profile ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@VonC is correct that you need a SSL Client Profile. You need to add it into the `User Agent` of your service:
[image]

The Fetch action will download the file to your DataPower `local:///` filesystem so you might as well download it manually and upload it to the DataPower instance though...

Answer (score 0):

This should be related to TLS selection, like the DataPower [service configuration variable](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.7.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/configurationservicevariables_reference.html) called [`var://service/tls-info`, or `serviceVars.tlsInfo`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.7.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/var-service-tls-info.html), which might not be properly set.

You would have then to define an [SSL *client* profile](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.7.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/sslprofiles.html) (which secures connections between the DataPower Gateway and its targets)